# Upscaling and sharpening 1080p image sequence to 4k in node editor?

Tags: node-editor

Hi I need to upscale 1080p .exr image sequence to 4k. I also want to apply a sharpen effect to it like: `-filter "unsharp=lx=7:ly=7"`
Or whatever blender can offer I guess will do. Using node editor cause there is no sharpen tool in the vse, unless there's an addon that's good for it...? I'd do it all in ffmpeg but it doesn't seem to support .exr image files.

I'm not very good at the node editor. I import them into the node editor as an image sequence, great. First thing I notice is if I change the resolution to 4k the images aren't scaled when in the node editor, how to fix?

The second thing is what nodes should I use to get the desired sharpen effect to clear up the upscale a bit? Should I be using cycles for this or does it not matter? its 30 minutes of footage, so shorter render is better unless the effect in cycles is profound.

I'm not sure if it would make more sense to simply upscale and render in the vse, and then apply the sharpen via ffmpeg, if that would re-encode and look bad or be the best method to do things.

Comment: When switching scenes's resolution to 4K, you should use image sequence with Distort->"Scale" node. Filter->"Filter" node has "Sharpen" mode. Render engine doesn't matter, but it is better to delete all geometry and set small amount of samples to speed up rendering process.